# C and string handling

Tags: c, data-structures, tree

FULL CODE http://pastebin.com/6bdVTyPt
My tree code was perfectly working until i found out i needed to validate the id that its not text so it had to be string
insertion function
string compare  of 90 and 129 returns 8
tried to use (atoi) and compare as integers does not work 
any help appreciated
thank you
**heres the insert function using atoi instead of strcomp** 
http://pastebin.com/yeuktyAF still not working
insertion function

```
   struct node * insert2(struct node *root, char x[],char id[])
 {
if(!root)
{
    root=(struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    free( root->data );
    free( root->id );// free previously allocated memory, if any
    root->data = strdup( x ); // malloc and copy
    root->id=strdup(id);
    root->left = NULL;
    root->right = NULL;
    //   printf("1\n");
    return(root);
}
printf("string comp %d of %s of %s\n",strcmp(root->id,id),root->id,id);
if((strcmp(root->id,id))>0){
    root->left = insert(root->left,x,id);
    printf("go left\n");
}
else
{
    if(strcmp(root->id,id)<0){
        printf("go right\n");
        root->right = insert(root->right,x,id);}
}
return(root);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The line

```
root=(struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
```

allocates memory for `root` but doesn't initialise it.  This means that the following lines

```
free( root->data );
free( root->id );
```

attempt to free uninitialised (so unpredictable) pointers.  This will almost certainly crash.

Since you've only just allocated `root` there can't possibly be any previous values in `data` or `id` to free.  This means you could simplify these three lines to

```
root=malloc(sizeof(*root));
```

Comment: i am new to memory allocation and this was a tip from somebody here on stackflow because it wasnt working

Comment: I'm afraid the suggestion to add the call to `free` was very poor advice.  You must do this if you have previously allocated memory for `root->data`; you **must not** do this for the uninitialised pointer you have in this case.

Comment: do u have any idea how can i compare numbers in strings?

Comment: If your string only contains digits, why not change it to be `int` instead?  If you really need to store it as a string, you can use [atoi](http://linux.die.net/man/3/atoi) to convert this into an `int` inside `insert2`

Comment: http://pastebin.com/yeuktyAF
@simonc try to do that not working :( sorry for ur time

Comment: I can't see any issues with that code.  Its possible the issue could lie in the calling code.  If you're still having problems, it might be better to create a small example program that demonstrates the problem and post it as a new question.

Answer (score 0):

You can't compare numerical strings using `strcmp()`. You should store your ID:s as integers, if that's what they are, so you can compare them directly.

That also has the benefit of less complexity, since integers are fixed size (assuming `unsigned long` is long enough) you won't need to use `strdup()`.

Also, [don't cast the return value of `malloc()` in C](https://stackoverflow.com/a/605858/28169).

Comment: yes okey the thing is i neeed to validate the id using 
    
    `code`  int validid(char a[]){int c,flag=0;
      for(c=0; (a[c])!='\0'; c++)
    {
        if(isalpha(a[c]))
            flag=1;
    }
    if (flag==1)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    else
        return 1;
    }